# How to print spaces between the words of a (string * n) operation?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a code that outputs the differences between two texts in terms of (words, times they appear) in a dictionary (key, value) form. I want to create a third text that contains just those words.
My code of

```
from collections import Counter
a = wordlist1
b = wordlist2
a_counter = Counter(a)
b_counter = Counter(b)

outcome2 = b_counter - a_counter
#print outcome2.items()
print " ".join (k*v for (k,v) in outcome2.iteritems())
```

does this very nicely - except for the way it compiles the clusters of the same word. I get:

> "uponuponuponuponuponuponuponuponuponuponupon
>   discoverdiscoverdiscoverdiscover student gestures
>   frequentlyfrequentlyfrequentlyfrequently laborious judgment
>   light-hearted destructiondestructiondestruction scarcely appropriated
>   offoffoff
>   iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
>   safiesafiesafiesafiesafiesafiesafiesafiesafiesafiesafiesafiesafiesafiesafiesafiesafiesafiesafie
>   wellwellwellwellwell thoughtthoughtthoughtthought insurmountable 111
>   command slenderly deadly ravineravine creators usualusualusual lest
>   lesslesslessless ambitionambition fancying aspirations recollection
>   distantdistant"

instead of "upon upon upon upon upon discover discover discover discover" etc.

I have tried simply putting in spaces like this

```
print " ".join (k* v for (k, v) in outcome2.iteritems())
```

which has no result.

I looked on stackoverflow for solutions to emulate like

```
print " ".join (k*(" " v) for (k,v) in outcome2.iteritems()) 
print " ".join (k*(" " + v) for (k,v) in outcome2.iteritems())
```

which resulted in syntax errors. Is it possible to insert a space within a (k,v) pair?

Comment: `k*v` -> `(k + ' ') * v`

Comment: Actually, you'll want `((k + ' ')*v).rstrip()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to insert the spaces you want is to have `join` do it. Instead of repeating strings with `*`, feed that many of the string to the `join` call. `Counter` conveniently provides a way to do that:

```
print ' '.join(outcome2.elements())
```

`elements` will produce an iterator that yields each key as many times as the count associated with it.

If `elements` wasn't a thing, you could do the repetition manually:

```
print ' '.join(k for k in outcome2 for i in xrange(outcome2[k]))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I already solved it based on Coldspeed's comment - but your solution is something I'll definitely keep in mind for similar codes

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with another `join` statement.

```
print " ".join (' '.join([k]*v) for (k,v) in outcome2.iteritems())
```